# Disable entire screen using topmost View

Tags: android, user-interface

On iOS I am able to take a simple view that simply fills the screen to disable any interaction  from the user.

This is used in conjuction with a progress bar/spinner during certain operations (saves, requests etc).

What is the best way to do this in Android? I have tried using a View/*Layout and filling the screen. It looks the same but doesn't block user touch events.

Currently I am using the above approach and have two functions { disableUI, resetUI }. It's quite cumbersome, though.

Any better approaches I'm not thinking of? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a FragmentDialog, or a Dialog (if you are using obselete APIs).

Here is an example

```
public class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    // ----------------------------------
    // CONSTANTS
    // ----------------------------------
    private static final String BUNDLE_KEY_TITLE = "BUNDLE_KEY_TITLE";
    private static final String BUNDLE_KEY_MESSAGE = "BUNDLE_KEY_MESSAGE";

    // ----------------------------------
    // ATTRIBUTES
    // ----------------------------------
    private String title;
    private String message;

    // ----------------------------------
    // PUBLIC METHODS
    // ----------------------------------
    public static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
        return createProgressDialogFragment(title, null);
    }

    public static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message)  {
        ProgressDialogFragment fragment = new ProgressDialogFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BUNDLE_KEY_TITLE, title);
        bundle.putString(BUNDLE_KEY_MESSAGE, message);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    // ----------------------------------
    // LIFE CYCLE
    // ----------------------------------

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // get params from the bundle
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.title = getArguments().getString(BUNDLE_KEY_TITLE);
            this.message = getArguments().getString(BUNDLE_KEY_MESSAGE);
        }
        dialog.setTitle(this.title);
        dialog.setMessage(this.message);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your "marks" on the code to define specific blocks, very easy to read +1

Comment: Decoration makes clean code. @the place where I work, we all do this, for all classes, all the time. Quality is high, and we have very good return on investment.

Comment: This code is great, I used it as a base to create a dialog with a custom view. A really nice UI enhancement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal `ProgressDialog` and set the cancelable to false. See below

```
ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(_context,
            progressString, "Please wait...",
            true);
progDailog.setCancelable(false);
```

You will have to run it in a seperate thread though. `AsyncTask` is preferable

Comment: Dialogs are really difficult to handle well, especially for long running operations like networking. It would be a lot of boilerplate code to prevent a leak from happening. That's what the fragment manager will do for you if you use a FragmentDialog...

Comment: I agree but in the question it did not sound like he was using fragments. Hence I did not use the DialogFragment